# Log4net RemoteSyslogAppender adding <14> to all message

Tags: elasticsearch, log4net, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using log4net with RemoteSyslogAppender to send logs to logstash/elasticsearch. 
The appender is automatically adding "<14>" in front of the message making it impossible to group stack traces.

This number comes before the identity value in every message that log4net sends. I have tried to add the "identity" tag with an empty value which have removed the "identity" of the message however the <14> was still there.

```
<identity value=""/>
```

Here is my current appender configuration

```
<appender name="RemoteSyslogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemoteSyslogAppender" >
  <identity value="somemessage" />
  <param name="RemoteAddress" value="10.3.145.130" />
  <param name="RemotePort" value="5140" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

with this configuration I am still getting the <14> right before the "identity" value (somemessage)

```
"message" => "<14>somemessage:    at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)",
```

The logstash configuration is irrelevant here but I can include it later if it helps, I am using {%GREEDYDATA} for now, and I will work on parsing this properly once I figure out how to group them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [RemoteSyslogAppender documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RemoteSyslogAppender.html) states it implements a client for the BSD syslog protocol, defined in [RFC 3164](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt). The `<14>` string is a part of that protocol and describes the facility and severity of the message, i.e. what part of the system emitted the message and how important it is. See §4.1.1 for the full description.

You can use grok to delete or extract this value, e.g. like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "<%{INT}>%{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
    overwrite => ["message"]
  }
}
```

If you want to convert the numerical value to something human readable you can use the [syslog_pri filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/syslog_pri).